# Cannot connect php site to mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, hosting

Hi I developed a php website with mysql. It worked perfectly on `localhost`. I hosted my site and change database config file,

```
<?php 
    define("dbhost", "128.199.145.183");
    define("dbuser", "root");
    define("dbpass", "xxxxxxx");
    define("dbname", "database");

    $dbc = new mysqli(dbhost,dbuser,dbpass,dbname);

 ?>
```

But it not worked. My site is working fine and when i tried to login i got an HTTP 500 error. How can i solve this?

Comment: You only use an IP address in rare circumstances, like if you're connecting to another site's host. You still use localhost on a live server. localhost simply means it's connecting to the site it's being hosted on.

Comment: @awl19 is sort of right, but plenty of shared hosts give you a different database server to localhost. Ultimately, check with your host. Also, what do your error logs say? 500 errors are internal, meaning it's a problem your side, so there will be errors logged to check.

Comment: Thanks you all. I checked error log and it says  `[11-Jul-2016 07:08:45 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.5.12/ext/php_intl.dll' - The specified module could not be found` . How to install it?

Comment: That means that problem is a missing PHP library, and it's not your mysql-connection. Google on how to enable PHP Intl on Windows.

Comment: that's warning, shouldn't be any issue. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: Thank you. I'll try

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo - You are correct. Didn't read it properly. Best thing though, while you develop your app, turn "display errors" on in PHP so you get a proper error message instead of just a "500 internal error". Then turn it back off when you got it working (although, you should see all the errors in the log, which you don't seem to, if that is the only error you got).

Answer (score 1):

`root` database user doesn't have by default access to access database remotely.

you can verify this by looking at the `mysql.user table`

```
use mysql;
select * from user;
```

check if root has the ip access from `%`

I would recommend, create another user with limited rights on host as `%` (can access database remotely)

You can create user like this:

```
use mysql; 
create user testing@'%' indentified by 'testing_password';
grant all on *.* to testing; // you can specify databases or specific permissions
flush privileges;
```